# how to set form element value in zend framework for editing

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend framework. I have done user registration and login but i can't do update user information because i don't know how to show form element value in update form.Please tell me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $editClientForm = new Form_AddNewClientForm();
    $editClientForm->setAction($this->view->baseUrl().'/client/edit');
    //fetch client data from your database through model
    $clientInfo = $mdlClient->fetchClientDetails($id);
    //populate the data to form
    $editClientForm->populate($clientInfo); 
    $this->view->editClientForm = $editClientForm;
```

### Update

After taking suggestion of @php-dev:

```
    $editClientForm = new Form_AddNewClientForm();
    $editClientForm->setAction($this->view->baseUrl().'/client/edit');
    //fetch client data from your database through model
    $mdlClient = new Model_Client();
    $clientInfo = $mdlClient->fetchClientDetails($id);
    //populate the data to form
    $editClientForm->populate($clientInfo); 
    $this->view->editClientForm = $editClientForm;
```

Inside your model:

```
    public function fetchClientDetails($id) 
    {
      $row = $this->_db->fetchRow("SELECT * from tablename where id = $id");        

      return $row;
    }
```

Comment: +1, but you shall mention that `populate` method accepts an `array` with fields names as keys and fields values as array values.